# Pandas: combining header rows of a multiIndex DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Lets say I have a DataFrame as follows:

```
first   bar       baz       foo
second  one  two  one  two  one  two three
A       1    2    3    4    5    6   7
B       8    9    10   11   12   13  14
```

and I want to create a new DataFrame like this:

```
        barone  bartwo  bazone baztwo  fooone footwo foothree
A       1       2       3      4       5      6      7
B       8       9       10     11      12     13     14
```

What would be the possible code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### 1. Update using Python 3.6+ use [f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) with list comprehension:

```
df.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df.columns]
```

#### 2. Use `map` and `join`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)
```

#### 3. If your columns has numeric datatypes, use `map` and `format`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
```

### Output:

```
   barone  bartwo  bazone  baztwo  fooone  footwo  foothree
A       1       2       3       4       5       6         7
B       8       9      10      11      12      13        14
```