# Pandas Combining header rows error: too many values to unpack

Tags: pandas, list-comprehension

I'm trying to follow the answer for this StackOverflow question: [Pandas: combining header rows of a multiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637153/pandas-combining-header-rows-of-a-multiindex-dataframe) because I have the same need.

I've put this data into foobar.txt:

```
first,bar,baz,foo
second,one,two,three
A,1,2,3
B,8,9,10
```

I want to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    first-second bar-one baz-two foo-three
    A            1       2       3
    B            8       9       10
```

I'm following the first answer to the linked question, which uses list comprehension, so my entire code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\foobar.txt')
df.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df.columns]
```

However, I get a **"too many values to unpack error"**:

```
Exception has occurred: ValueError
too many values to unpack (expected 2)
  File ".\test.py", line 32, in <listcomp>
    df.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df.columns]
  File ".\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    df.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df.columns]
```

I've looked at other examples where folks hit the same error and I'm certain it's due to the fact that I have more than 2 values from df.columns, but I'm not sure how to fix that, nor do I understand why the answer I linked to above doesn't hit this problem.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\foobar.txt', header=[0,1])` you should specify the header lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to read the CSV by specifying the header rows to get `MultiIndex`

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\foobar.txt', header=[0,1])

df.columns

MultiIndex([('first', 'second'),
            (  'bar',    'one'),
            (  'baz',    'two'),
            (  'foo',  'three')],
           )

df.columns = [f'{i}{j}' for i, j in df.columns]

df.columns

Index(['firstsecond', 'barone', 'baztwo', 'foothree'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: This is the same solution I just got from a fellow at work and it works great!
I'd vote it up if I could, but my reputation is insufficient.

Comment: You can accept it as right answer :)

Comment: Done! the site didn't let me accept the answer yesterday, but it did today. Thanks for your help!